# Return number of the last occurrence of a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying, with no sucess, to get a number inside of the **last occurence** of a pattern inside of a HTML code. The pattern is `data\\[\d{1,3}\\]`. How can i get the number `03` in the below example?

```
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>
<p>TEST</p>
<p>data[01]</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>data[02]</p>
<p>TEST</p>
<p id="demo" test=data[03]></p>
</body>
```

I tried many combinations with $, but I could not make it work.

Comment: so why are you just just reading it from the html?

Comment: @PM77-1 look again....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
/data\[(\d{1,3})\](?![\s\S]*data\[\d{1,3}\])/
```

1. `data\[(\d{1,3})\]` for matching your pattern and `(...)` is for capturing the digit value.
2. `(?![\s\S]*data\[\d{1,3}\])` is negative lookahead asserion, in current case this helps to match any `data-{digit}` format string which doesn't follows the same format anywhere after that. Where `[\s\S]` is used to match anything since `.` excludes newline character.

```js
const data = `data<body>
<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>
<p>TEST</p>
<p>data[01]</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>data[02]</p>
<p>TEST</p>
<p id="demo" test=data[03]></p>
</body>`

console.log(data.match(/data\[(\d{1,3})\](?![\s\S]*data\[\d{1,3}\])/)[1])
```

[Detailed Regex explanation and demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fOlgxS/1).

---

**UPDATE :** If it always the `test` attribute's value of the `p` tag then you can use `DOMParser` or a dummy DOM element to do the trick since RegExp is not a good method to parse HTML.

REF : [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

1. Using [DOMParser](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```js
const data = `data<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>data[01]</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p>data[02]</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p id="demo" test=data[03]></p>
    </body>`

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");

console.log(doc.querySelector('p#demo').getAttribute('test').match(/\d+/)[0])
```

2. Creating a dummy element

```js
const data = `data<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>data[01]</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p>data[02]</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p id="demo" test=data[03]></p>
    </body>`

// create a dummy element and set content
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;

console.log(div.querySelector('p#demo').getAttribute('test').match(/\d+/)[0])
```

Comment: This is almost what i'm looking for but i can make it work with this. This returns all the lat pattern "data[03]" but i can use replace and strip all the non digits. It's possible to get the number with one regex (just for learning purposes)? Many thanks.

Comment: @MarkF :  You can get the capturing value `console.log(data.match(/data\[(\d{1,3})\](?![\s\S]*data\[\d{1,3}\])/)[1])`

Answer (score -1):

JS `.match()` returns an array, so just get the last array item from that: `arr[arr.length - 1]`

```js
var htmlString = document.body.innerHTML;
var match = htmlString.match(/data\[\d{1,3}\]/g);
console.log("ALL MATCHES", match);
if (match) {
  console.log("LAST MATCH", match[match.length - 1]);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>
  <p>TEST</p>
  <p>data[01]</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p>data[02]</p>
  <p>TEST</p>
  <p id="demo" test=data[03]></p>
</body>
```